# ui-select2 and number values - auto converted into strings

Tags: angularjs, ui-select2

I'm using `ui-select2` in my angular project.

My model downloads a complex object called `Field` which has multiple properties in it(a `Field` has a title\value and other things).

Now to be specific, my `Field` has two relevant properties `Value` and `Options`.

`Options` is a key value array object which contains `Value` and `Text`. It's specific for a select-box.

The `Text` property is a string value(display) where the `Value` property is usually a Number, but can be a string.

Bottom line, my select2 template looks something like this:

```
<select ui-select2="select2Options" ng-model="model">
    <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option.Value}}">{{option.Text}}</option>
</select>
```

Pretty trivial..
My problem is that the ng-model converts the selected option's `Value` into a **string**(e.g. 2 -> "2") and by doing that, I get problems with the selected value after it returns from the server(since 2 !== "2").

I've debugged deep into the sources and couldn't find a good work around.

I tried using `ng-options` this way:

```
<select ui-select2="select2Options" ng-model="model" ng-options="opt.Text for opt in options">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

But then my `model` got the key-value **object**.
Now I can think of an **ugly** work around by adding a dummy ng-model property and adding a watch on the scope which will assign the `Value` to the "real" model - but I don't want to do that.

Does anyone have any advice for me?